# how to remove some data from pe (exe) file in C

Tags: c++, c, executable, portable-executable

in first exe i have defined array of char with some special bytes as label, i mapping it to memory from another exe, finding needed label and putting in it new data, but this data could be shorter then defined array, so i want to cut this array to needed size! how can i do it?

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way of achieving what you want to do without resorting to ugly non-portable hacks like this. Maybe you could say what it is that you are *really* trying to achieve ?

Comment: i working on file encryption program, and first exe is like a stub with defined big array of "nops", it is big because a i dont no size of data that will be inputed in it from second exe. SO if inputed data will be much smaller then that array, i must cut it for reduce exe file size. I know that it will change offsets but dont know how to update them correctly. that's it!

Comment: Why not implement your encryption as a library and link to it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fine and simple way to cut out pieces of PE file.

Obvious solution is to additionally define a `length` field in the original (in your terms *first*) exe and mark it with another label. Then additional work of second exe would be to write to this field actual data length.

---

EDIT: If cutting is your primary goal you must also keep in mind that:

- Control sum of a PE will change. Location of control sum field in PE header is not hard to find though.
- PE file is aligned. All sections are aligned. The alignment could be found in the header too.
- If you cut one section it would cause **great** consequences. Take a look at PE file header structure.

[image: header]

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx